# Associativity of the Kac-Moody OPE

Tags: conformal-field-theory

The Kac-Moody OPE reads
\begin{equation}
J^a(z_1)J^b(z_2)\sim \frac{k\delta^{ab}}{2(z_{12})^2}+\frac{f^{abc}J^c(z_1)}{z_{12}}+\mathcal{O}(z_{12}^0)\text{ descendants}\qquad (1)
\end{equation}

However, due to the color indices, it is not at all clear how this OPE is associative,

\begin{equation}
\Bigg(\Big(J^a(z_1)J^b(z_2)\Big)J^{c}(z_3)\Bigg)\overset{?}{=} \Bigg(J^a(z_1)\Big(J^b(z_2)J^{c}(z_3)\Big)\Bigg)\qquad (2)
\end{equation}

where brackets denote which operators we OPE together first. For example the LHS of (2) reads
\begin{equation}
\Bigg(\Big(J^a(z_1)J^b(z_2)\Big)J^{c}(z_3)\Bigg)\sim \frac{k\delta^{ab}J^{c}(z_3)}{2(z_{12})^2}+\frac{kf^{abe}\delta^{ec}}{(z_{12})^2z_{13}}+\frac{f^{abe}f^{ecg}}{z_{12}z_{13}}J^g(z_3)+\text{ descendants}\quad (3)
\end{equation}

whereas on the RHS of (2) we have

\begin{equation}
\Bigg(J^a(z_1)\Big(J^b(z_2)J^{c}(z_3)\Big)\Bigg) \sim \frac{k\delta^{bc}J^{a}(z_1)}{2(z_{23})^2}+\frac{kf^{bce}\delta^{ea}}{(z_{23})^2z_{13}}+\frac{f^{bce}f^{eag}}{z_{23}z_{13}}J^g(z_3)+\text{ descendants}\quad (4)
\end{equation}

Examining $(3)$ and $(4)$ it is not at all clear how an equality $(3)=(4)$ can hold, in particular due to the color indices.

Question: Is there a simple way to check the associativity of $(1)$?

Comment: Concerning conventions, are you following a reference? Which pages?

Comment: Eq.(1), the Kac-Moody OPE is taken from Becker, Becker, Schwarz; "String theory and M-theory" page 68, Eq.3.54.

Comment: might be useful if you consider first the simpler case where there are no color indices, i.e., $U(1)_k$, where the OPE is just $J(1)J(2)=\frac{k}{z_{12}^2}$. In checking associativity make sure you are expanding around the same point!